# How to add a url(having a webseal) in wfs service of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am using QGIS 2.18 version.I am trying to add a new connection in wfs. That url is having a webseal. While I am trying to add a new connection in the WFS, the log message i showing like this:

```
Download of capabilities failed: Host requires authentication
```

I have given the username and add basic authentication also. Is it Possible with other versions?